# Prove that $(n\log{n})^{-1/2}\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} X_i \rightarrow \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be iid with density $f(x)={\begin{cases} 0, if \mid x \mid \leq 1 \\ \mid x \mid^{-3} , if\mid x \mid >1\end{cases}}$. Prove that $(n\log{n})^{-1/2}\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} X_i \rightarrow \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution.

My thoughts: I want to usc CLT on this problem and I can do some transformations: $original=\frac{\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} X_i - 0}{\sigma \sqrt n} \times \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\log n}}$ and I'm stuck here. The hint is to truncate $X_i$ at $\pm \sqrt{n\log n}$, but I'm a little confused by this hint.

Comment: You can't use CLT out of the box as $E(X^2)=\infty$. But if you truncate $X_i$ as hinted, you can get around this difficulty as you as can get around non-existence of $EX$ for weak law of large numbers.

Comment: I don't know how to do this either.